# Why do my WP7 settings take so long to load?

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I put a stopwatch on it. The first time the app loads (no settings file exists) it takes about 190ms to fail to load four settings. The app runs, three bools and a short string are written as settings, and the next time the app loads, it takes 400ms to read the first setting from the IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings collection and about 1ms to get the remainder.

Is there *anything* I can do to ameliorate this load time?

Comment: Is there any difference in loadtimes between the emulator and a physical device? Are you using exceptions to detect the 'first load'?

Comment: I don't use the emulator. It uses too much RAM on my workstation which is an elderly notebook that takes a maximum of 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

Ues a better Serialization method ;)
XMLSerialization is okay for more complex graphs, but for simple settings, binary serialization would be much better. Also, when you say `fail to load`, I assume you're doing a check to see if the files exist? If not, I think there may be exceptions being thrown internally which would slow down execution as well.

Comment: Poor wording perhaps. By "fail to load" I mean that it doesn't load because it doesn't exist on the first pass. Presumably it is then created as an empty collection.

Comment: In the case I suggest trying to use binary serialization for the settings and see if that improves the load time.